# Symfony2 form - date field validation doesn't work

Tags: forms, symfony

When I submit form the text field containing date isn't validated although I defined constraint in entity. What is incorrect? Do I need to write custom date validator for text field containing date?

In my form class I have

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('added', 'date', array(
                'required' => false,
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'datepicker'
                )
            ))
}
```

In entity

```
/**
 * @var date
 *
 * @Assert\Date(message = "test")
 * @ORM\Column(name="added", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $added;
```

And in controller (I need those errors listed)

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $r = $this->getProfileRepository();
    $profile = $id ? $r->find($id) : new \Alden\XyzBundle\Entity\Profile();
    /* @var $profile \Alden\XyzBundle\Entity\Profile */
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $profile);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($profile);
        foreach ($errors as $e)
        {
            /* @var $e \Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation */
            $errors2[$e->getPropertyPath()] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        if (count($errors2))
        {
        ...
        } else {
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($profile);
            $em->flush();
        }
```

Comment: Where does `$errors2` come from when the valudation is being assigned to `$errors`. Is that a typo?

Comment: I didn't copy all code and apparently cut too much. I added missing lines.

Comment: Is there something else missing? You are binding the $request to $form and then validating $profile. Presumably you are doing something like $profile->setAdded($form->getData()->getAdded()) somewhere?

Comment: No I don't - everything is handled by Sf2 forms component. I added more code to controller.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your configuration. According to the [Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) section of the Symfony2 book:

> The Symfony2 validator is enabled by default, but you must explicitly enable annotations if you're using the annotation method to specify your constraints:

For example:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

Comment: There are other fields (like firstName) which are validated correct (as not empty and min length = 3)